# import long number from csv into access

Tags: c#, csv, ms-access

I want to import csv file to access database, mostly of the data is a 'long' number.
The problem was those 'long' number convert to scientific notation.
Said in csv is 90049699515564500, after import into access is 9.00496995155646E+16

the access database table1 i did set all the column Date type: Text , Field Size: 255

Here is the csv
colA,colB,colC
123123,123123,123123
**90049699515564500**,123123,123123

here is the access table1 result after import
colA,colB,colC
123123,123123,123123
**9.00496995155646E+16**,123123,123123

here is the C# code

```
string strQryCommand = "INSERT INTO table1 "
                     +  "SELECT colA, colB, colC "
                     + @"FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;Database=C:\someDir].[file.csv]";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessDatabase"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = strQryCommand;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Any idea how can i save the 'long' number as string/text?

Comment: I use SELECT Format(colA,\"#######################\") as colA, colB, colC. But, here come another problem, the number is wrong when digit is too long, the conversion is wrong. csv: 8610592400381810, access: 8610592400381820.csv:90049699515564500,access:90049699515564600

Answer (score 3):

Try with CDec:

```
string strQryCommand = "INSERT INTO table1 "
                     +  "SELECT CDec(colA), colB, colC "
                     + @"FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;Database=C:\someDir].[file.csv]";
```

or use CDec to convert the data after import when reading it.

Comment: It give me error: Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression CDec(ColA).

Comment: There is one argument only, but perhaps you have Nulls in ColA? Try with `CDec(Nz(ColA),0)`.

Comment: Try CDec(Nz(ColA),0) Error: Undefined function 'Nz' in Expression. Try CDec(IIF(IsNull(ColA),0,ColA),0) Error:Overflow.

Comment: Then I would prefer: `"SELECT IIf(colA Is Null, Null, CDec(colA)), colB, colC "` or perhaps: `"SELECT CDec('0' & colA), colB, colC "`.

Answer (score 1):

Force a conversion format:­­­

```
SELECT Format(colA,\"0000000000000000\") as colA, colB, colC­­­­
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is most suit my solution. i use # instead of 0. SELECT Format(colA,\"#######################\") as colA, colB, colC­­­­

Answer (score 0):

Open the table in design view. Select the field and set the Format to Standard. No additional manipulation of data needed.
[image]

Comment: M Access? I don't see 'standard' in format. try used format(ColA, "Standard") in query string, but failed.

Comment: What query string? Open the table in design view from within Access. In the lower portion of the window, under Field Properties, on the General tab, there is a Format property. Click in the empty space and a dropdown button will appear. Open it and select 'Standard'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I try all the method suggested here. But no one really solve my problem, import csv numeric number more that 16 digits using Ole DB query. The are 2 alternative solutions,

1. Massage the csv before the process, add quote on those numeric number: "12345678901234567".
2. Using stream reader instead of using Ole DB query.